# 効率良く配列の範囲を取り出したい

Tags: c#

## 質問

タイトルの通りですが「効率良く配列の範囲を取り出したい」です。

低レベルのプログラムを書いているため、メモリの範囲読み出しが頻繁に発生しています。
よって、効率を求めています。

質問内容の「効率良く」いう言葉の意味は以下の通りです。
- メモリコピーが少ないもの
- メモリアロケーションが少ないもの
- CPU使用率が低い物

`Stopwatch`を利用した簡単な処理速度比較のベンチマークは書いたことがあるのですが、
メモリアロケーション等を考慮したベンチマークはどのように書けばよいか分かりません。

同じ結果が得られるプログラムを以下5つ思いついたのですが、どれが最も効率が良いでしょうか？
※以下5つ以外でも、効率の良い書き方があれば紹介して頂けると助かります。

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

      // 方法1. LINQ
      bytes = bytes.Skip(1).Take(3).ToArray();

      // 方法2. C#8 Ranges and Indices
      // bytes = bytes[1..4];

      // 方法3. Span
      // bytes = bytes.AsSpan(1, 3).ToArray();

      // 方法4. Buffer.BlockCopy
      // var tmp = new byte[3];
      // Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 1, tmp, 0, 3);
      // bytes = tmp;

      // 方法5. Array.Copy
      // var tmp = new byte[3];
      // Array.Copy(bytes, 1, tmp, 0, 3);
      // bytes = tmp;

      // 出力: 02-03-04
      Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCが長さ３の`byte[]`配列を作成するコストが最も高いため、コピー方法の差は微々たるものです。

効率を求めるのであれば、`Span<T>`やポインター等を使い、そもそもコピーしないことを検討すべきです。

なお、方法１ LINQは複雑な処理を簡単に表現することを得意としますが、逆に質問のような低レベルでパフォーマンスを求める処理は不得意です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Spanを利用して書き直すことにします。